# Python Custom configuration Parser

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to read below configuration from Python , But I am not able to map the values to config parser in a proper way

```
school {
  class-1 {
    nine {
      address = [ "address1" ]
      pincodes = "123,890,899"
    }
  }
  class-2 {
    eight {
      address = [ "address2" ]
      pincodes = "123,890,899"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to get the *pincodes* values , Verify and update if there is a change in the books.

as of now reading the file line by line and identifying the match then replacing the content of a line. Below the code

```
#this will be a derived value from other file. hard coding here for ref. example
replacement_text='           pincodes = "900,800,879"'
for line in fileinput.input(["school_ledger.txt"], inplace=True):
    if line.strip().startswith('pincodes'):
        line = replacement_text + '\n'
    sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Instead of reading the file line by line, Is there any possibility to map the content to any python parsers, so that it will be more generic.

The file content format wouldn't change.

Comment: Then post the relevant Python code.

Comment: The respondents on this site are volunteering their time and energy to answer your questions.  Please honor this commitment by taking the time to prepare a clear concise question that includes a complete [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") containing both data, and code that can be copied and pasted along with a clear description of what is wrong with your current effort.

Comment: Yes. Agree. Edited the code with my work. I am looking for a more generic solution.